# architecture for cloud text files parser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a bunch of text files (>150k) on a server. The file sizes are quite small. Usually between 20-50kb. I can call an API to that server to get a download link to download individual files separately. I need to design a system on AWS cloud to parser the content of each file and generate a report. Essentially just check whether a pattern exists on each individual file. There is a rate limit to call the API. I tried to use a sequential approach but it was too slow. I need to parallelize the process. The list of files is currently stored in a text file.

I already have an eks cluster. I would like to use an app on an eks cluster to trigger lambda function to parse the logs. but I need a mechanism to track the status of each file. Do I need a database? or just something like elastic cache?

Comment: If you want to check any pattern from AWS console, my suggestion would be to keep those files in S3 and use Athena.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it, is to build 2 types of Lambda functions:

1. Get list of all files and put for each file a message in SQS. Decide how to trigger this function (e.g. scheduler, HTTP endpoint).
2. Listen to a new messages on that queue and process the file that corresponds to the received message. Single file at each invocation. You will need to set `BatchSize` to 1 to guarantee single SQS message per Lambda invocation.

The potential concurrency you get with default settings is 1000. You should limit it via `ReservedConcurrentExecutions` to the rate limit of the API you are calling.